# Почему не работает Get запрос?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

```
public ActionResult PhotoList(string category)
{
    ViewData["PhotoList"] = (from p in dataManager.Photos.GetPhotos()
                 where p.category == category
             select p).ToList();
    return View();
```

Есть вот такой нехитрый метод в контроллере, вызываю его

> /Galleries/PhotoList/Macro

Так вот ничего не возвращается. Вопрос - в чем может быть проблема? 
ЗЫ. если категорию указать сразу т.е.

```
 where p.category == "Macro"
```

все работает.

Comment: Стало быть, category на самом деле не равно "Macro", не так ли?

Comment: Случаем не /Galleries/PhotoList/?category=macro ?

Comment: А Вы не пробовали посмотреть, что возвращает category?

Comment: категория - может быть равна макро, или еще какой-то из категорий.
/Galleries/PhotoList/?category=macro  - пробовал -тоже не работает

Comment: если ``where p.category == "Macro"`` работает, то очевидно же, что проблема в ``ActionResult PhotoList(string category)`` посмотрите в дебагере, что находится в ``string category`` во время запроса, если ничего, то проблема в роутах, если же находится строка ``Macro``, то даже не знаю в чём проблема(проблема во вьюхе может быть)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, в Global.asax MapRoute неправильно прописан? Нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // ...
    routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{category}");
}
```

Comment: тут все правильно, да и если пересылать параметром int - то отрабатывает